# cordova SMS plugin -- javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova 3.6.3.
I am using following SMS plugin.

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.rjfun.cordova.sms
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/tree/master/docs

I have added plugin in following way :--
cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.sms

My cordova app when loaded calls the following function doc_onload().

```
<body onload="doc_onload()">
```

Then this register the handler for "deviceready". When the device is ready this device ready function is called.

Now the problem inside the  `initApp()` handler is that SMS plugin check does not display any alert message.
I am able to get the alert --> "kk" .

But in the following check  `if (! SMS )` I did not get any display message.  Neither `if nor else` got satisfied.

Even `alert("end");`  Does not get displayed  inside `initApp()` event handler.

Please suggest why it is failing ?

```
function initApp()
{
    alert("initApp");
    // attach Fastclick handler
    FastClick.attach(document.body);

    alert("kk");

    if (! SMS )
    {
        alert( 'SMS plugin not ready' );
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        alert( 'SMS plugin Ok ' );
    }

    alert("end");

    //add SMS arrive listner handler
    document.addEventListener("onSMSArrive", processSMS(), false);


}

//function doc_onload(page_type)
function doc_onload()
{

   // Do some task
    alert("doc_onload");

    // add event handler for deviceready function
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", initApp(), false);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the brackets from 'initApp()' in

document.addEventListener("deviceready", initApp, false);

EDIT ** The above is just for semantics

I think you need to change !SMS to

```
typeof SMS === 'undefined'
```

Comment: if i remove the brackets from initApp() ... initApp is not called at all in the cordova app ... but if i add bracket this event handler is called in the cordova app .. can you suggest why ?

Comment: I use to get an alert output as :--
alert( 'SMS plugin not ready' );

Comment: I have added SMS plugin in following way :--
cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.sms

But why object SMS is not defined in the cordova app ?

Comment: Have you added the SMS.js file from the creator's github?

Comment: I am referring  this example :-- https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/test/index.html from author. This is not adding SMS.js file .

Comment: This link have an index.html example to refer. To use this sms plugin ...http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.rjfun.cordova.sms

Comment: Yes thats how you use it but you need to add the SMS.js in yout file or define it yourself

Comment: Ok thanks.. but why Author of plugin have not used this SMS.js file in the reference example ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe they forgot in the example. But add the SMS.js and it should work

Comment: This is the solutionhttps://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phonegap/fSLH7J9YgLI